# "unsigned :(number)" and Unions

Tags: c++, unions

i dont know whats mean "unsigned :5",

for example if i create these:

```
int a:8;
unsigned b:8;
```

is b a integer?

and another question:

in a union with these values:

```
union
   { long quad;
      long duble;
      char byte;
       struct {
      unsigned :16;
    unsigned :16;
     unsigned :16;
     unsigned :15;

     unsigned bit1:1;
       } bits;
   }pes;


pes.quad=0x12345678;
pes.duble=0xabcd;
pes.byte=0xef;
pes.bits.bit1=1;
```

why in `Adress` is: `ef ab 00 00 cc cc cc cc`

I thought it would be      `ef ab 34 12 00 00 00 80`

Comment: Those are *bit fields*.

Answer (score 1):

The `:` introduces a [**bit field**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), which is a value in a struct of a particular logical type but with an actual size measured in bits. This is useful for defining structures that access individual bits of a value (e.g. to extract flag bits from a word).

For example, defining `unsigned b:5; unsigned c:3;` would make `b` and `c` share the same byte in memory, where `b` would be 5 of the bits and `c` would be the other 3 bits.

Comment: and if you define: unsigned b:2; ?? is only 2 bits, or 1 byte with 2 bits but the another bits is trush?